# React.js get asset from database on `componentWillMount` asynchrnonously

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, asynchronous

I am writing a react component where on navigation, the component should `get` some `json` from the db in a `async` manner. Currently my code is

```
    constructor(props) {

        super(props);
        this.state = { name : false }

    }

    componentWillMount(){
        this.loadNameA()
        .then (_ => console.log('loaded NameContainer'))
        .catch(e => console.log(`Error ${e}`))
    }
```

where

```
loadNameA = async () => {
    const val = await User.getName()
    // do some logic here
    this.setState({ name : val })
}
```

I ran the function `loadNameA` twice, both times with the `async` prefix Once w/o the `await User.getName()` call to the backend, and once with the call the backend. When I call the backend I get error :

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` supplied to `Editor`, expected a Slate `Value` but received: false
```

This is because I initalized the value of `name` to be `false` in `constructor`. In essence the component mounted without waiting for the async call to end, even though I am `await`ing the response from `loadNameA`. How can I ensure the component mounts and its state is appropriately resolved after the `async` call?

Comment: can you please make a mock app on https://codesandbox.io/, so that we can reproduce and debug the problem?

Comment: you are not awaiting the response FROMloadNameA. You are awaiting the response IN loadNameA but componentWillMount is not waiting for your call to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply provide your `render()` method something to `return` `if (!this.state.name)`.

See below for a practical example.

```js
// App.
class App extends React.Component {

  // State.
  state = {name: false}
  
  // Render.
  render = () => <div>{this.state.name || 'Loading ..'}</div>
  
  // Did Mount.
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getName()
    .then(name => this.setState({name}))
  }
  
  // Get Name.
  getName = () => new Promise(r => 
    window.setTimeout(() => r('NAME'), 1000))
  
}

// Mount.
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```